# How can I wrap the subscript into a math environment in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have some subscripts in my org file like `B_25`, `B_30`. These subscripts can be exported to LaTeX like `B_{25}`, `B_{30}`. However, I want part of the subscripts like `B` to be exported as italic *B*. As one solution for this, I can wrap these thing into a math environment like `\(B_{25}\)`. But since my file contains large numbers of these subscripts, I just want to write the `B_25` in org file and export as `\(B_{25}\)` to LaTeX file in a programmable way.

I found a subscript filter function in org-mode, so I tried to use it to wrap the subscripts by

```
(defun wrap-subscript-with-math-environment (contents backend info)
  (when (eq backend 'latex)
   (format "\\(%s\\)" contents)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-subscript-functions 'wrap-subscript-with-math-environment)
```

However, the results exported are like `B\($_{\text{25}}$ \)`. It seems like the subscript filter contents only contain `_25` part. Does anyone have some solutions about this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just find and replace all subscript occurrences in your file once? Eg. `M-x replace-regex` `\([[:alnum:]]+\)_\([[:alnum:]]+\)` `$\\textit{\1}_{\2}$`.

Comment: This is still cumbersome. Because I always add new subscripts, I need to do the replace many times.

Comment: looking at `org-element-subscript-parser`, I'm not sure this is worth the hassle. You'd have to (temporarily) extend the `org-match-substring-regexp` to include the symbol before the subscript.